# Import some classes from another war file deploy on same server

Tags: spring, maven, war

I have a java web application which is deployed on tomcat server. Then I have another application which contain webservice using spring oauth2. This also is deployed on the same tomcat server. The webservice application use the same dao /service and model classes as the java web application. Currently I have replicate the classes in the webservice. If there is a change, I need to replicate it on both side. I'm asking if is there a way to call the dao/model classes from the java web application into the webservice application (without duplicate the classes on both side) ?Both projects is using maven.

Comment: I try to following this guide : https://eureka.ykyuen.info/2009/10/30/maven-dependency-on-jarwar-package/

But I'm not able to generate the jar file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the same set of classes is needed in two applications, put these classes into a separate jar, deploy it with Maven and put it as dependency into the poms of the Maven projects that use it.

Comment: Thanks I manage to do it like in the above url. But when i generate WAR file using mvn clean install, some classes throw Unresolved compilation. Do you know why?

Comment: @Alina If you have an additional question, please open up a new question on stackoverflow. Also add detailed error messages.